Is there a way to have a landing page screen before my tab bar shows up in a react native and expo router app?
So I have a react native app that I created using the Tamagui expo-router template, that comes with builtin tabs, but I want to have a "landing page" of some sort that has some introductory info and has a few buttons that would redirect the user to a page on the tab bar (and after they clicked the button, the tab bar would show). How would I implement something like this, and where would I keep the "landing page" component relative to my app layout, and have it without a tab bar (and have it add back the tab bar after the button is pressed)? Below is my current _layout.tsx
import { DarkTheme, DefaultTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { SplashScreen, Stack } from 'expo-router'
import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native'
import { TamaguiProvider } from 'tamagui'

import '../tamagui-web.css'

import { config } from '../tamagui.config'
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import React from 'react'

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from 'expo-router'

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: '(tabs)',
}

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()

export function loadFonts() {
  const [interLoaded, interError] = useFonts({
    Inter: require('@tamagui/font-inter/otf/Inter-Medium.otf'),
    InterBold: require('@tamagui/font-inter/otf/Inter-Bold.otf')
  })

  return [interLoaded, interError]
}

export default function RootLayout() {
  // const [interLoaded, interError] = useFonts({
  //   Inter: require('@tamagui/font-inter/otf/Inter-Medium.otf'),
  //   InterBold: require('@tamagui/font-inter/otf/Inter-Bold.otf'),
  // })

  const [interLoaded, interError] = loadFonts()

  // const [interLoaded, interError] = useFonts({
    // Inter: '../assets/fonts/Inter-Medium.otf',
    // InterBold: '../assets/fonts/Inter-Bold.otf'
  // })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (interLoaded || interError) {
      // Hide the splash screen after the fonts have loaded (or an error was returned) and the UI is ready.
      SplashScreen.hideAsync()
    }
  }, [interLoaded, interError])

  if (!interLoaded && !interError) {
    return null
  }

  return <RootLayoutNav />
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme()

  return (
    <TamaguiProvider config={config} defaultTheme={colorScheme as any}>
      <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
        <Stack>
          <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="TossupSettingsModal" options={{ presentation: 'modal', title: 'Tossup Settings' }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="BonusSettingsModal" options={{ presentation: 'modal', title: 'Bonus Settings' }} />
        </Stack>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </TamaguiProvider>
  )
}


I tried to create an index.tsx file and add it as a <Stack.Screen> in my  component, but I had no luck doing that.
